# Doesn't do anything - simpleXML PHP

Tags: php, simplexml, notice

It's not doing anything when I run it...
I suppose It should write something like:

> O nás Produkty

Here is the PHP code (line 50 because it's inside HTML code):

```
<?php
$menu=simplexml_load_file('menu.xml') or die('Cannot read menu!');
foreach((array) $menu->menu_items->item as $HTMLTAG)
{
echo $HTMLTAG;
} 
?>
```

And here is a part of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu_items>
<item link_url="#" active="on">O nás
<subitem link_url="/about" active="on">O nás</subitem>
<subitem link_url="/about/reference" active="on">Reference</subitem>
<subitem link_url="/about/contact" active="on">Kontakty</subitem>
</item>
<item link_url="#" active="on">Produkty
<subitem link_url="/HeatMatrix" active="on">O nás
<under_subitem link_url="/HeatMatrix/LUVO">Předehřívač vzduchu LUVO</under_subitem>
<under_subitem link_url="/HeatMatrix/HV">Hybridní výměníky</under_subitem>
<under_subitem link_url="/HeatMatrix/KP">Výměníky kapalina-plyn</under_subitem>
<under_subitem link_url="/HeatMatrix/VCS">Vestavěný čistící systém</under_subitem></subitem>
<subitem link_url="/OCR" active="off">OCR systémy</subitem>
<subitem link_url="/LDR" active="off">Točivé redukce</subitem>
</item>
</menu_items>
```

Don't you know what should I do about it?

Comment: Where do you think the `items` group is?

Comment: You are right! I missed it! Thanks. xD

Comment: But... When I deleted from PHP code the items, it didn't write absolutely anything... Like it was totally empty...

Comment: Check your error logs.  Here's it's complaining that the encoding isn't proper UTF-8.

Comment: --- That could be local to my setup, obviously ;-)

Comment: Nope... Here it says that there is no error... It's working "correctly" from view of Google Chrome... From my view there is some kind of error I cannot find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->menu_items` also does not need to be there, since it is the root node of the XML document. This worked for me:

```
foreach($menu->item as $HTMLTAG)
{
    echo $HTMLTAG; //I used print_r here actually, which was nicer.
}
```